# Make icon appear on top right of the box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I would like to make the question mark on hover appear on the top right part of the white box. Currently, it is appearing on the bottom left part of the white box.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="rptTitle">
      <br />
      <br />
      Text here....... text here......
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="questionBox" data-original-title="More Information" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle grayColor"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grayColor {
  color: #A6A6A6;
}

.panel {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.panel:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.panel:hover .panel-heading {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.panel .questionBox i {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.panel:hover .questionBox i {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kow5np4q/2/)**

I tried using `position:absolute;` and using `right, top` but that wouldn't help me if I have multiple divs

**UPDATE:**

**[image]**

Comment: Added a demo to the post

Comment: I think you may be confusing the use of `position: absolute` with this statement *but that wouldn't help me if I have multiple divs*.  The question marks would be absolutely positioned inside of each question boxes, so, yes, absolute position *could* help you here. The answers below will give you the result you want.

Comment: Is there a way without position absolute? @ᴉʞuǝ

Comment: Floating the element to the right should give something close to what you're wanting, either approach would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should relatively position your outer `panel` and then you can absolutely position your icon.

Try the following solution:

```
.panel {
  position:relative;
}

.fa.fa-question-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gfprfvu/)**

The reasoning for this is because absolutely positioning something positions an item relative to it's first ancestor element that is positioned non-statically. This is the reason for the relative positioning to the `panel`.

Picture a box. The box has a relative positioning. Anything inside of that box that is positioned absolutely has a maximum height/width of that box. So when you position the icon absolutely and use `top: 0; right: 0`, you get it to the top right of that box. In this case, the box is the `panel`.

**UPDATE**

Given your new criteria, you can try something like this:

```
#rptTitle {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}

.questionBox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

It's a quick and dirty solution, but fits your needs. Use the concepts to build it better :)

**[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stxeff10/)**

Comment: Also, I don't want to use position absolute

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with `position:absolute;` but you also need to set the parent element to `position:relative;`. Lastly add `top:0px` and `right:0px` to the question mark element.

With the updated post you will need to also move the div inside the div with the class `panel-body` and make sure `panel-body` is `position:relative;`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wowsk/okmvyjd9/)

Comment: Also, I don't want to use position absolute

Comment: Updated post and Fiddle

Comment: question mark's position is not right in the fiddle... Please check the picture where the question mark needs to be

Comment: Is this better? Play around with how far from the top the icon is too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.questionBox > * {
  position: absolute;
  top:65px;
  right: 25px;
}
```

Live example:

(updated) https://jsfiddle.net/kow5np4q/7/

Another approach (without `position: absolute`)

https://jsfiddle.net/kow5np4q/8/

The 3rd approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/kow5np4q/10/

And with the 3rd approach, you don't need to use `<br>`s. Use padding instead.

Comment: I don't want to use position absolute

Comment: Check the second approach